# Error while trying to preview data in DataFlow in Azure Synaspe

Tags: azure, apache-spark, hive, azure-synapse

I have a data pipeline in Azure Synaspe. The Pipeline has a data flow activity that is reading data from a Spark database in Azure Data Lake Storage Gen 2 data lake. The data then sinks into another spark database.

The other day when I tried to preview from the source spark database, I got the following error(data source name is masked).

*at Source '<>': org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: MetaException(message:null);*

This was working perfectly fine previously.

Please note: There were no code changes to this pipeline.

Any thoughts

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `Autoscale` of Spark pool configuration is Enable.

You should try by increasing Number of nodes.

Also try with more Node Size.

[image]

Reference - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/706694/unable-to-run-sql-queries-in-azure-synapse-error-o.html

Comment: Thank you for posting. Autoscale is already enabled. The number of nodes available are between 3 to 10. However will keep trying playing around with the node size.